# How to igone a jackson array element on the basis of a property value?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have an incomming json of this format which im receiving from api A

```
{
  person:[
{
 "name": "A"
 "gender": "male"
},

{
 "name": "A"
 "gender": "female"
},

{
 "name": "A"
 "gender": "male"
}
]
}
```

i want to filter the elements with gender as female and give a response json on my endpoint of a format like this

```
{
  person:[
{
 "name": "A"
 "gender": "male"
},

{
 "name": "A"
 "gender": "male"
}
]
}
```

is there a way to do this during mapping/serialization using jackson annotations

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person{

 private String name;

 private String gender;

 //getter setters
}

@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JsonResponseModel{
  private List<Person> person;

  //getter setter

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609079/how-to-filter-the-json-response-returning-from-spring-rest-web-service

Comment: i dont think so....i dont want to hide the json property rather i want to ignore the whole element if the property value is "female"

Comment: you want to filter out female elements, which means you need to filter JsonResponseModel for females. If I'm not mistaken, that question's response provides exactly this. Alternatively, you can just manually filter out jsonResponse before sending it.

Comment: i'm restricted to do it manually like i'm restricted to delete elements from list rather i am advised to only map/serialize only those which meets the criteria, is there a way?

Comment: which element do you recieve? if JsonResponseModel then filter on that, otherwise don't add elements that you receive from Person. Please read the link more carefully.

Comment: @Zunair Fatimi above answer you can use in front-end but in java you have to use JSONPATH like this String jsonString="json string you want to filter";
String jsonpathExpresion="$.person.[?(@.gender=='female')]";
JsonNode femaleJSon = JsonPath.read(jsonpathExpresion, jsonString, JsonNode.class); in femaleJSon you get female filtered json.

Comment: @ZunairFatimi This article appears to describe what you're looking for : http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can filter any json using `JsonPath` for getting only female person data from json use this link [jsonPath checking](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com).

Use this json path to get all female persons.

```
 $.person.[?(@.gender=='female')]
```

And format your json using [json fomatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) .

Put json and jsonpath in first link you get filtered json which shows you female gender data.

Comment: seems like a jquery solution...im working in java spring boot environment.

Comment: to use in java you need to use my second answer